# listing in minipage sucks content of previous page to the bottom

Tags: listings, page-breaking, minipage

I'm working on a document that contains many listings (namely code samples) but not a lot of text. Most of these listings are only a couple of lines long, and a few span multiple pages. At the end of a page, a break is inserted in the middle of a listing.

[image: screenshot #1]
<sub>(source: [warmonkey.org](http://warmonkey.org/files/stackexchange_tex_lstlisting_pagebreak_001.png))</sub>

**I don't want short listings to be broken across pages. Rather, short listings should just be moved to the next page, leaving some white space at the end of the previous page.** The ideal solution would be if I could define a threshold for listing size beyond which listings are broken across pages, but below which the listings are automatically moved to the beginning of the next page.

[image: screenshot #3]
<sub>(source: [warmonkey.org](http://warmonkey.org/files/stackexchange_tex_lstlisting_pagebreak_003.png))</sub>

I haven't found anything like this on the web. **At least I've found out how to prevent single listings from being broken across pages, namely by putting them into a minipage.** By putting small listings into minipages but leaving long listings as they are (by hand), I almost have what I want.

**The problem I have, however, is that when a listing is moved to the next page, the listings (and the text) on the previous page is "sucked" to the bottom of the page**! This results in whitespace between the title and the beginning of the content, instead of between the end of the content and the end of the page, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. I'm sure that there's some way to prevent this, I just have no clue how...

[image: screenshot #2]
<sub>(source: [warmonkey.org](http://warmonkey.org/files/stackexchange_tex_lstlisting_pagebreak_002.png))</sub>

Below is a sample code *(note that it's only that long because I didn't find any way to fill the listings with random text, so I had to insert lots of placeholder text manually)*. The minipage commands are commented, the code corresponds to screenshot #1. If the minipage commands are uncommented, the result looks like screenshot #2. What I want it to look like is shown in screenshot #3 (achieved by uncommenting the pagebreak).

**EDIT**: Added twoside to documentclass *(the initial sample code could not reproduce the comment because I removed twoside right before posting, now knowing that that actually caused the problem)*.

```
%#############################################################################
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
%#############################################################################

\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text

\usepackage{fixltx2e} % textsubscript and textsuperscript
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{frame=single}

%#############################################################################
\begin{document}
%#############################################################################

%""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
\section{A few listings}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\lipsum[2]

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

%###\noindent\begin{minipage}{\hsize}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=foo]
not
such
a
huge
listing
\end{lstlisting}
%###\end{minipage}

%###\noindent\begin{minipage}{\hsize}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=foo]
yet
another
short
one
,
though
a
bit
longer
\end{lstlisting}
%###\end{minipage}

%###\newpage

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

%###\noindent\begin{minipage}{\hsize}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=foo]
this
one
is
a
bit
larger
,
so
it
doesn
not
fit
onto
the
page
anymore
!
but
it
still
fits
on
one
page
!
\end{lstlisting}
%###\end{minipage}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=494,label=code:assoc494,caption=foo]
this
particular
listing
on
the
other
hand
is
a
lot
longer
than
the
one
before
!





















...



























finally
it
is
coming
to
an
end
!!
\end{lstlisting}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

%#############################################################################
\end{document}
%#############################################################################
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please always post the code in a form that _demonstrates the problem_. If I uncomment the begin and end minipage lines, the first page is left short with all the space at the bottom as I would expect. the stretched version is what I would expect from `\flushbottom` but that is not the default with `article`

Comment: You could use the needspace package for your "threshold".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed, I'm suddenly not able anymore to reproduce the problem myself, neither in my sample code nor in the original document I'm working on! Now this is just bizarre, after all I wouldn't have gone through the trouble of preparing this question (let alone produce the screenshots) if the problem wouldn't have been there (and reproducible) before...

Comment: the image shows the difference between `\flushbottom` and `\raggedbottom` but your example uses `\raggedbottom` in all cases.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the hint, this might really do the trick! But even apart from my specific problem (although it seems to have disappeared in thin air...) the package is great, I wanted to be able to do something like this for a long time (but I've apparently never searched for it thoroughly enough).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks a lot for trying to help me, strange that the problem is not reproducible anymore. With \flushbottom it indeed looks like the screenshot, but I'm 100% positive that there was no \flashbottom in the code at any point. Maybe the problem will surface again, I just might have removed something unsuspicous from the sample code during the final cleanup that caused the issue. I'll surely double-check the code once again before hitting the butten next time when posting a question!

Comment: Perhaps you remove the twoside option. This would switch to raggedbottom.

Comment: @flotzilla  we don't like to leave questions left open, so should we vote to close as unclear? (or you could delete or...)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that's exactly what I did! I thought that would only affect the left and right margins (little did I know)... I'll edit the sample code and add a note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images show the difference between `\flushbottom` and `\raggedbottom`, adding `\raggedbottom` to your preamble (which is the default for single side `article) will cause LaTeX to pad any short pages with stretchable space at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Do you have any idea why `onesided` defaults to `\raggedbottom` but `twosided` to `\flushbottom`? As mentioned in my comment above, I'd have though the only difference between `onesided` and `twosided` would be the lateral page margins!

Comment: @flotzilla mostly because it's always been that way. Arguably if printing two sided its more likley that you see two sides at once, so different length pages are more distracting. Perhaps. But Leslie Lamport's original code made this distinction without additional comment some time last century and that's just how it is:-)